# Undefined reference resulting from g++ linking

Tags: linker, g++

I am new to g++ and Makefile. I am trying to link this BeBOP SMC library, which is in my lib directory. Under the lib directory are bebop_util and sparse_matrix_converter, both of which have already been built without errors. I see libbebop_util.a, libbebop_util.so under bebop_util and libsparse_matrix_converter.a, libsparse_matrix_converter.so under sparse_matrix_converter. Below is the source:

Makefile

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

test.out: test.o
    $(CC) -o test.out -Ilib/sparse_matrix_converter/include -Llib/bebop_util \
-Llib/sparse_matrix_converter -lbebop_util -lsparse_matrix_converter test.o

test.o: test.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Ilib/sparse_matrix_converter/include test.cpp

clean:
    rm -f test.o test.out
```

---

test.cpp

```
#include <bebop/smc/sparse_matrix.h>
#include <bebop/smc/sparse_matrix_ops.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    struct sparse_matrix_t* A = load_sparse_matrix (MATRIX_MARKET, "sample_input");
    destroy_sparse_matrix(A);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
login3% make
g++ -c -Wall -Ilib/sparse_matrix_converter/include test.cpp
g++ -o test.out -Ilib/sparse_matrix_converter/include -Llib/bebop_util -Llib/sparse_matrix_converter -lbebop_util -lsparse_matrix_converter test.o
test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `load_sparse_matrix(sparse_matrix_file_format_t, char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `destroy_sparse_matrix(sparse_matrix_t*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test.out] Error 1
```

---

Please note that test.cpp depends on sparse_matrix_converter, which depends on bebop_util. Would you please let me know what mistakes I may have made? Thanks.

Tom

Comment: you're linking against -lbebop_util -lsparse_matrix_converter, both of those names don't look like they would be main libraries. Are you sure you linked everything?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I have linked to everything. sparse_matrix_converter is the main library. The library is called BeBOP SMC. SMC stands for sparse matrix converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BeBOP code looks to be C code but hasn't add the correct C++ guards.  Surround your includes with `extern "C"` to fix that:

```
extern "C" {
#include <bebop/smc/sparse_matrix.h>
#include <bebop/smc/sparse_matrix_ops.h>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The compile errors are gone with the addition of extern C. However, I got a new error: ./test.out: error while loading shared libraries: libbebop_util.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I made sure the permission is not the problem through chmod 777 for libbebop_util.so.

Comment: I'll just accept the answer since the new problem seems a different one. I'll post the new problem.